# whitespaces absorbed at the beginning of a LaTeX equation in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I need to insert some spaces (`\quad`) at the beginning of an equation such as `$\quad x$`. But the `\quad` is silently absorbed by org-mode when the embedded LaTeX is converted to an image.

I did some research and saw from this [TeX exchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318454) that

> TeX removes spaces if they appear at the start of a line. You can
> insert a null object at the start of the line to prevent this.

So I tried, as the answer there suggests, to add a `\null` before the `\quad`. But still, the leading whitespace does not show up. I also tried the longer form as well as `\hspace*`, to no avail:

```
\begin{equation}
\null\quad\quad x
\end{equation}
```

The issue seems to be specific to org-mode. Hence the question:

*How can I get leading whitespaces such as `\quad` to display correctly?*

(This is with org-mode 29.1, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

Comment: For me, `\null\quad\quad x` has definetly more white spaces than `x`. [see this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/msitxzG)

Comment: @Garid I meant that the embedded LaTeX image generated when previewing an equation has this issue. The screenshot you showed seemed to be a complete PDF export (with the TOC etc). I think the two results can be different.

Comment: Ah I see, you were talking about `org-latex-preview` (?). I overlooked the "embedded LaTeX is converted to an image" part. I agree I see same as you described

Comment: Are you using `dvipng` as the value for `org-preview-latex-default-process`? If so, `dvipng` is called with a `-T tight` option which just preserves "the ink": anything that is not inked is discarded (e.g. leading and trailing whitespace). "Preview" is just that: it's an approximate representation of what you'll get when you export it.

Comment: "...anything that is not inked is discarded" - that's not quite right. Everything outside the smallest rectangle that contains all the inked areas is discarded, but e.g. in `\( x \quad = 3\)` the white space between the `x` and the `=` is retained.

Comment: @NickD I am using `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)` as I read dvipng have problems sometimes with the LaTeX preview.

Comment: In the `imagemagick` case, `convert` is called with the `-trim` option, which I suspect does the same thing: it gets rid of the "edges", everything outside the bounding box. Once the fragment has been converted to PDF (or DVI in the `dvipng` case), there is no way to distinguish between "intentional" whitespace (that you add) from "accidental" whitespace: it's all whitespace and gets eliminated.

Comment: I actually have more problems with `imagemagick` than I have with `dvipng` nowadays, but I'm not quite sure why yet. The bounding boxes are huge (relatively speaking).